# Git won't push into a bare repository on server

Tags: linux, git, gitolite

I just installed Gitolite on a server, so any repositories that I'm pushing into on it should be bare repositories, and I've even went into the repo directories, and ran `git init --bare` in them to make sure that they are bare, but when I try to push into them, I still get this error message:

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

I even ran `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore` to try to get it to just push into the remote repo, but the error still comes up.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Check this link: http://bitflop.com/tutorials/git-bare-vs-non-bare-repositories.html - It explains the differences between bare and non-bare repos.

Comment: Updating the link URL posted in the comment http://www.bitflop.dk/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-and-empty-branch-in-git.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that if there is a user on the Gitolite server that Git will log into that user instead of through Gitolite, and I didn't realize that.  And I also had a copy of the repo I was trying to push in my user directory, and so of course it wasn't bare.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to run a `git init --bare` yourself.

Simply declare a new repo name in the `gitolite.conf` file of the `gitolite-admin` repo, push that back to the gitolite server, and gitolite itself will create that repo properly (in `~/repositories/mynewrepo.git`, as a bare repo)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I started out doing, and it was giving me this error.

Comment: @supercheetah it gives you that error when you are declaring a new repo in the `gitolite.conf` file and pushing it to the gitolite server? Do you have a `.gitolite.rc` file in that gitolite home dir on that server?

Comment: That's correct, and yes, there is a `.gitolite.rc` file.